# Start only one animation with onTap

Tags: flutter, dart, widget

I have an issue with the onTap widget, in my case it allows to start a small animation. My issue is that when i press the button of the menu, i want only one animation start, the other(already active) must return to their initial state. Thank you for your help

whole code :

**main.dart**

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import './button.dart';

void main() => runApp(const MyStatefulWidget());

class MyStatefulWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyStatefulWidget({Key key}) : super(key: key);
  @override
  State<MyStatefulWidget> createState() => _MyStatefulWidgetState();
}

class _MyStatefulWidgetState extends State<MyStatefulWidget> {
  List<bool> selected = [false, false, false, false, false];

  Container countryPageView() {
    final PageController controller =
        PageController(initialPage: 1, keepPage: true, viewportFraction: 0.35);
    return Container(
      height: 300,
      child: PageView.builder(
        scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
        controller: controller,
        itemCount: 5,
        physics: BouncingScrollPhysics(),
        itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
          return Container(
            child: gestureDetectorOntap(index),
          );
        },
      ),
    );
  }

  GestureDetector gestureDetectorOntap(int index) {
    return GestureDetector(
      onTap: () {
        setState(() {
          selected[index] = !selected[index];
        });
      },
      child: Column(
        // pass selected for this button
        children: [
          Text('menu $index'),
          button(selected[index])
        ], // animation function
      ),
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        body: countryPageView(),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Animation with AnimatedContainer

**button.dart**

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import './main.dart';

button(bool selected) {
  return AnimatedContainer(
    width: selected ? 200.0 : 100.0,
    height: selected ? 100.0 : 200.0,
    color: selected ? Colors.red : Colors.blue,
    alignment: selected ? Alignment.center : AlignmentDirectional.topCenter,
    duration: const Duration(seconds: 2),
    curve: Curves.fastOutSlowIn,
    child: const FlutterLogo(size: 75),
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

replace

```
setState(() {
      selected[index] = !selected[index];
    });
```

with

```
setState(() {
      selected = [false, false, false, false, false];
      selected[index] = !selected[index];
    });
```

Comment: Thanks bro, that work fine , but i don't know why at the start of the code  i must leave this line : 
`List<bool> selected = [false, false, false, false, false];`  and add this one : `selected = [false, false, false, false, false];`  because these line are repetitive.
when i try to replace that `List<bool> selected = [false, false, false, false, false];`  by that `List<bool> selected ;` , i have an error .

Comment: You need to instantiate the list before using it. Thats why you get an error when only using `List<bool> selected;` --> Here: `button(selected[index])` your code tries to access selected. But if it is null, there is nothing to access. This results in an error. What my code does is set every entry to false, thats why its repetative. You could also loop through the list an set everything to false. Would be the same.